# AWS client VPN can't resolve DNS server

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, vpn, vpn-client, aws-vpc

I am swapping out a wiregaurd vpn running on an EC2 instance with a AWS client VPN so that i can use MFA with google. I have most of what i want in place, but i am stuck on setting up the VPN to use my DNS server.

About my configs:

- Set up the CIDR block of my VPC as 173.0.0.0/16 so my DNS
  server should is at 173.0.0.2.
- aws console set the DNS server entry of the VPN to 173.0.0.2
- The client associated to a
  public subnet to allow internet traffic out (i can ping the ip for
  google and it comes back with data)
- I have set up auth rules to allow 0.0.0.0 thought, but also get an auth rule from the associated network to let that though
- I have in the route table one entry that points back to the public subnet with the internet gateway on it
- That subnet has 173.0.0.0/16 local **this is where i think my issue may be**

So basically when i turn on the VPN i can ping IPs and get data, but it will can not reach the dns server.

i think it could have something to do with my route table not properly forwarding to the VPC?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of ipconfig /all (windows), or similar on other platforms. Check where your OS is looking for DNS. I'm finding your description a little difficult to understand. Can you please also include Client VPN configuration screenshot and screenshots of relevant security groups / route tables.